# Rewrite JSON structure using cypress

Tags: cypress

```
[
  {    
    "routineCode": "StudentMapping",
    "routineId": "NIL",
    "routineClass": "NIL",
    "routineUpdate": "NIL",
    "routineMap": "Create-Role-Grade"
  },
  {    
    "routineCode": "createRole",
    "routineId": "791",
    "routineClass": "POCOD1",
    "routineUpdate": "Yes",
    "routineMap": "Create-Role"
  },
  {    
    "routineCode": "createGrade",
    "routineId": "3094",
    "routineClass": "DWR145",
    "routineUpdate": "Yes",
    "routineMap": "Create-Grade"
  },
  {    
    "routineCode": "StudentMapping",
    "routineId": "NIL",
    "routineClass": "NIL",
    "routineUpdate": "NIL",
    "routineMap": "Edit-Role-Grade"
  },
  {    
    "routineCode": "EditRole",
    "routineId": "791",
    "routineClass": "POCOD5",
    "routineUpdate": "Yes",
    "routineMap": "Edit-Role"
  },
  {    
    "routineCode": "EditGrade",
    "routineId": "3094",
    "routineClass": "DWR298",
    "routineUpdate": "Yes",
    "routineMap": "Edit-Grade"
  },
  {    
    "routineCode": "StudentMapping",
    "routineId": "NIL",
    "routineClass": "NIL",
    "routineUpdate": "NIL",
    "routineMap": "Delete-Role-Grade"
  },
  {    
    "routineCode": "DeleteRole",
    "routineId": "791",
    "routineClass": "POCOD5",
    "routineUpdate": "Yes",
    "routineMap": "Delete-Role"
  },
  {    
    "routineCode": "DeleteGrade",
    "routineId": "3094",
    "routineClass": "DWR298",
    "routineUpdate": "Yes",
    "routineMap": "Delete-Grade"
  } 
]
```

The JSON file have the above data. The JSON object from JSON file have been stored like this in Cypress:

```
const jsonObjectRoute = require('../../fixtures/routeMap.json');
```

Now, this json object need to be reframed as like below using Cypress. Then, need to open 1st for loop to print the routineCode and routineMap and 2nd for loop to print the items.
Could anyone help on this?

```
[
    {    
        "routineCode": "StudentMapping",
        "routineMap": "Create-Role-Grade"
        "items": [
            {    
                "routineCode": "createRole",
                "routineId": "791",
                "routineClass": "POCOD1",
                "routineUpdate": "Yes",
                "routineMap": "Create-Role"
            },
            {    
                "routineCode": "createGrade",
                "routineId": "3094",
                "routineClass": "DWR145",
                "routineUpdate": "Yes",
                "routineMap": "Create-Grade"
            },
        ]
    },
    {    
        "routineCode": "StudentMapping",
        "routineMap": "Edit-Role-Grade",
        "items": [
            {    
                "routineCode": "EditRole",
                "routineId": "791",
                "routineClass": "POCOD5",
                "routineUpdate": "Yes",
                "routineMap": "Edit-Role"
            },
            {    
                "routineCode": "EditGrade",
                "routineId": "3094",
                "routineClass": "DWR298",
                "routineUpdate": "Yes",
                "routineMap": "Edit-Grade"
            },
        ]
    },  
    {    
        "routineCode": "StudentMapping",
        "routineMap": "Delete-Role-Grade"
        "items": [
            {    
                "routineCode": "DeleteRole",
                "routineId": "791",
                "routineClass": "POCOD5",
                "routineUpdate": "Yes",
                "routineMap": "Delete-Role"
            },
            {    
                "routineCode": "DeleteGrade",
                "routineId": "3094",
                "routineClass": "DWR298",
                "routineUpdate": "Yes",
                "routineMap": "Delete-Grade"
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Why can't you just update your `json` file?

Comment: I'm sure you manipulate your data and wrap it in a `cy.task()`. I'm not sure what if it will be a one time change or repeated.

Comment: This JSON file would be used by multiple teams. So, I cannot modify the JSON file. The only option I left was to reframe the JSON object as above in code.